# Exception handling part in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, error-handling, exception

I have below error handling part in the last section of my dynamic procedure. But it is not working correctly. What is wrong in below error handling part. Please make it correct.

```
IF @@ERROR <> 0 GOTO ErrorHandler

SET NOCOUNT OFF

RETURN(0)

ErrorHandler:
    Return(@@ERROR)

New Method 1

declare Int @Errorcode;

IF @@ERROR <> 0 GOTO ErrorHandler

    SET NOCOUNT OFF

    RETURN(0)

ErrorHandler:

       @Errorcode= @@ERROR

       Return @Errorcode;

New Method 2:

BEGIN TRY
EXECUTE SQL @QUERY
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
SELECT 
ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,  
ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;  
END CATCH
```

GO

Comment: If by not working correctly, you mean the return code is zero, it is because `@@ERROR` contains the error code from the last executed statement (`GOTO`). You need to save `@@ERROR` in a variable and return that value instead. Also, consider TRY/CATCH.

Comment: Thank you.As per your suggestion i made changes in my error handling part.I listed two methods in my orginal posting now(New Method 1,New Method 2).Please suggest me which is good method.I do not have any output parameters in my procedure.it contains only dynamic select statement.

Comment: The best thing would be to read [this blog](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html) I think you'll find a lot of answers you will come up with there. .

Comment: @Ram, if were using a supported SQL Server version (SQL 2012 or later), you could simplify with 'THROW' to re-throw the original exception that could be caught and handled on the client side.